# How to display the today date in contact form 7 without datepicker

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i want to display the current date (today date the date off submission of the form)  in field date in contact form 7  without choosing it using the datepicker,i want also to disable the datepicker if it's possible.please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this script.

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
   var now = new Date(); 
   var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
   $('#MydatePicker').val(today);
   $("#MydatePicker").attr("min", today);
});
</script>

[date* your-date class:required id:MydatePicker]
```

Please check it.

Comment: it doesen't work i install headers and footers plugin to add the custum script that u gave me:<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
   var now = new Date(); 
   var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
   $('#id:MydatePicker').val(today);
   $("#id:MydatePicker").attr("min", today);
});
</script> and insert the shortcode: [date* your-date class:required id:MydatePicker]  inside the contact form 7 but it doesen't show the current date. it shows just aaa-mm-dd

Comment: it works i delete just the "id:" before "MydatePicker" in the the script and it works fine.thanks Ankit.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
[date* your-date "today"]
```

With that you achieve the same result as with Ankit's solution.